# View M value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, m-values

I've got a ".shp" file (plus the additional .dbf, .fix, .prj, .shx files) that was created using the [geotools](https://github.com/geotools/geotools) library and want to view its data using [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org) 3.8.2.

QGIS properly displays all of the points in the .shp file and clicking on the "i" button and then on one of the points displays its information at the right-hand side:

- Name
- ID
- X
- Y
- Z

The only thing missing is the "M" value. I know this is probably a very basic question but I can't find any information about it anywhere: How do I get access to the M value?

I don't want to edit it or create new ones, I just want to see the existing one. Is there maybe any type of table that has a list of every point in the .shp file and all of its values (XYZ, M, name,...)?

Comment: You could try running the `Extract M values` from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `M` value attached to your data?

Comment: @Joseph Found it: I selected the point - "Extract M values" - selected the "Input Layer" in the new window, added all 16 "Summaries to calculate" and clicked on "run". This added an "m_first" entry on the right but the value is "NULL". Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Erik Yes, I've got the code here: It creates an `ExtendedCoordinate` for every point (`new ExtendedCoordinate(4500000+p*10,5500000+p*p,100+p%5,p )`, p is just the iterator of a "for" loop) and adds this object to a `SimpleFeatureBuilder`. So it should be there. Does QGIS usually display the M value right from the start?

Comment: @Joseph I also tried setting an M value with "Set M value", which created a new layer, then used "Extract M values" on the point but all "m_xxx" values are still `NULL`. I really think I'm missing something important here.

Comment: I suspect the shapefile itself isn't a pointzm type. Try doubling clicking the layer in the layer tree and double checking the actual layer geometry type.

Comment: @ndawson The "Information" option lists: "Geometry: Point (PointZ)". So I'm guessing, writing the M value didn't work after all? :/

Comment: Correct - there's no M value info there.

Comment: The old code didn't work then. :/ I updated geotools to the latest version and now the type is automatically set to "PointZM" and there's even an M value, even though it's 0. No idea how to set it though, so if anyone knows, please post in my new [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/333902/148791).

Comment: What is M value?

Comment: @nagib First google [result](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/285318/148791).