# Can QField be set to automatically collect points?

Tags: qgis, qfield

My workflow requires me to collect a position and time stamp every second during a survey. Work in remote areas requires an offline solution like QField. It appears QField may not have an automatic setting to collect positions/time stamp but I’m not a QField super user so figured I’d ask the crowd before continuing my search for a solution.

Anyone have ideas how I can collect x, y, and time at one second intervals in remote areas?

Comment: You can enable tracking (automatic vertex digitisation every x seconds/metres) using the [QField app settings](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/tracking/). If you enable this on a line layer that has supports the M-dimension or M-values (often saved as geometry type LineStringM), the timestamp is recorded in the M value for each vertex.  Have a look at that first. Read this for more about M values https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285316/what-does-m-value-represent/285318#285318

Comment: Using your instruction, I’ve created a M-enabled point layer with an attribute field called [time_doubl] and set the data type to double. I was able to import the layer to QField and collect points at 1 second intervals. That’s partial success. Unfortunately, when I import my new track points back to QGIS there is no time data in my time field. Is the time stamp stored elsewhere. Do I need to use field calculator to pull it into the attributes?

Comment: The time is stored in the M dimension which isn't automatically shown in the attribute table (much like the geometry column). You can extract it using [`m()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#m)

Comment: That worked. I used m() in the field calculator to populate a new column. It’s in Unix epoch time so needs to be converted to date/time for my purpose but I can deal with that.